# Is $\mathbb{R}^{2} \times \{0\}$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be $\tau$. I am confused that whether  $\mathbb{R}^{2}\times \{0\}\in \tau$?

Comment: Hi @user450201, please ask a new question in a new post, not as an edit to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. An open set $O$ in $\mathbb R^3$ satisfies: for any point $p\in O$, there exists an open ball centered at $p$ that is contained in $O$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the image of $\Bbb R^2 \times \{0\}$ under the third projection $\pi_3 : \Bbb R^3 \ni (x, y, z) \mapsto z \in \Bbb R$:

$$\pi_3\big(\Bbb R^2 \times \{0\}\big) = \{0\}$$ This is not an open set of $\Bbb R$.

So $\Bbb R^2 \times \{0\}$ cannot be an open set of $\Bbb R^2$ as projection maps map open sets to open sets.

Comment: @AntoineMathys Thanks for pointing out the typo

Answer (score 1):

No.  Take any point of the form $(x,y,0)$.  Since the topology on $\Bbb R^3$ is the product topology, any open set $U$ containing $(x,y,0)$ intersects $\Bbb R^3\setminus (\Bbb R^2×\{0\})$ nontrivially.

That's because the product topology is generated by sets of the form $(a,b)×(c,d)×(e,f)$, for $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\Bbb R$.  (The set $U$ will thus contain elements of $\Bbb R^3$ with third coordinate nonzero.)